# Angular http Response header is null

Tags: angular

I am trying to get a response header sent by the backend.
I am getting a different behavior wether I use a debug mode or not.

```
this.totalCount = Number(response.headers.get('x-total-count'));
```

When I use Chrome Debugger with VisualStudioCode, I get the totalCount sent by the backend. But, when I use the browser directly, the totalCount is null.
I checked the debugging mode params, and I found that the parameter that is making that code works as expected is this parameter:

```
"--user-data-dir"
```

I tried with angular 5.0.2 and 5.0.5; mac, windows and linux; chrome, safari and firefox.
The backend is an expressjs app.

Comment: Which http client are you using? The old one (Http) or the new one (HttpClient)? If using the new one you need to specify `observe: 'response in the request options. Show show code if you've done all of that

Comment: I am using HttpClient. And I specified observe:response. Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/9gXCWuKn